# TimePicker value not changing property after loading value

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-toolkit

I have a `TimePicker` control from `Windows Phone Toolkit` placed on my settings page:

```
<toolkit:TimePicker x:Name="DayStartTimePicker" ValueStringFormat="{}{0:t}"></toolkit:TimePicker>
```

It works fine until I want to load a previously saved value to it

```
DayStartTimePicker.Value = SomeDateTimeValue;
```

After this, I can tap on the control and choose the time, but after confirming it the field's value remains unchanged (it has the `SomeDateTime` time, but not the one I selected).

I guess I'm missing something, but I couldn't find anything on the internet to fix that issue.

Comment: In which place do you make assigment?

Comment: Root `Grid` element on `Loaded`, because otherwise it would throw me a `NullReferenceException`

Comment: `Loaded` event calls every time when page is loaded, even after `TimePicker` page execution comes back to this page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your scenario, `DayStartTimePicker.Value = SomeDateTimeValue;` is called in `Loaded` event, which calls every time page opens, i.e. when`TimePicker` is closed and execution comes back to this page, so selected value is overwrites by old one. You must set default value in page constructor:

```
// page constructor
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
    // will be called in first frame render, i.e when page is loaded and builded
    DayStartTimePicker.Value = SomeDateTimeValue;
});
```

Comment: I used a trick with setting a `bool` value that determines if the page has loaded or not, but this is what was happening. Thanks!